# Htaccess rule not applying

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in my htaccess file to remove .php extension and do a 301 redirect to the extensionless URL:

```
# To remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To check whether the file exists then set it back internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]
```

I want to apply the following rules on a PHP file:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The above rule leads to 500 internal server error. If I remove the first set of rules, the second rule works again. So, there is some conflict with both set of rules.

Answer (score -1):

You must enable the RewriteEngine with `RewriteEngine On`, in your `.htaccess`.

If you got an Error, check your `error logs` on your `WebServer` - Here you find the answer, why an `500' error` appears.

Comment: I already have this line at the beginning. There is some conflict with those rules together